# schedule an asynctask after a variable time duration every time in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using a `timeschedular` in android to schedule an `AsyncTask` in my app.I was able to work it out well,now i want every time the duration after which the task runs to be changed i am using this code

```
  ip=3000;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {       
                try {
                    play_duration=durat.get(vn);
                     ip=Integer.valueOf(play_duration);
                       ip=ShowImages.ip*1000;
                    Showtime s1 = new Showtime();
                    s1.execute(what,f12,transi,play_duration);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0,ip);
```

i am trying to change the value of ip variable every time in the thread but it do not change and i do not know why my thread always run after the initial value of ip that is 3000 miliseconds, can someone suggest a way to do it..thanks

Answer (score 0):

to change component on the UI use the runOnUiThread,
see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), [here](http://sharecoding.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/simple-runonuithread-for-update-view-on-android/) and [here](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/ui-thread/) to do that thing on the background you can use something like -

```
while(true) 
{
  runOnUiThread() {
    do some stuf here;
  }
  Thread.Sleep(300); //<--- that should be nothing for the user and enough for the cpu 
}
```

if you need more accurate answer post your code and ill guide you through

Comment: i am showing a high resolution image in the asynctask thread,so i am converting the image to the bitmap and showing the image in the asynctask,i presume that if i will try to convert the image on the main ui thread the thread will become unresponsive

Comment: Well that changes thing a bit, you can still use that piece of code but just use new Asynctask().execute() instead of runOnUiThread and do your processing on the doInBackground part, anyway if you're not making this app for tablets I would consider downgrading the image to improve general performance (I did that on an app I developed there is no difference on the picture and the performance raised significantly...)